# JavaScript function not searching through array

Tags: javascript, browser, browser-detection

I've written a bit of code in JavaScript that uses the `window.navigator.language` and the `navigator.browserLanguage` objects to search through an array which contains these possible values.

What I am trying to achieve is to check through an array to see if any of the values within it match the browser language. I am aware that you can use PHP and check the HTTP header but I need to have this check performed client side. Anyway, I've written the code which is below but for some reason it doesn't seem to return the values I want. I've written the function on the basis that each time the browser language matches a value in an array it will return true, else it will return false. However each time I run the function it just returns true! What am I doing wrong? Code is below.

JavaScript:

```
var langArray = new Array("en","en-GB","en-US","fr","de","en-gb","en-us"); 

function checkforIE() {
    if (navigator.browserLanguage) { //if the navigator.browserLanguage is supported (IE only)
        for(var i=0;i<langArray.length;i++) {
            if(this[i] = navigator.browserLanguage) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}

function checkforFirefox() {
    if (window.navigator.language) { //if the window.navigator.language is supported 
        for (var i=0;i<langArray.length;i++) {
            if(window.navigator.language==this[i]) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="test-browser.js"></script>
<title>Test Browser support</title>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Test browser support</h2>
<a href="#" onclick="checkforIE(); checkforFirefox();">Click here</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: im not sure why it always return true but unless im mistaken those functions will only check the first element and then return.  The other elements in the array will not be checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this[i]` should be `langArray[i]`. You're expecting `this` to refer to `langArray`, but that's not correct. `this` refers to `window`.

Also, you're not doing anything with the return values. To combine your function behaviour, use:

```
var lang = checkforIE() || checkforFirefox(); //If IE, use IE, otherwise, use FF
if(lang) alert('Language supported');
```

Answer (score 1):

- You're assigning instead of comparing
- You should fetch from the array, not from `this`
- You should only return false if all failed. Currently you're always returning after the first iteration. If the first element doesn't match the function should not directly return false but continue checking for the second element, etc.

For example:

```
function checkforIE() {
    if (navigator.browserLanguage) { //if the navigator.browserLanguage is supported (IE only)
        for(var i=0;i<langArray.length;i++) {
            if(langArray[i] == navigator.browserLanguage) { // == for comparison
                                                            // and fetch from the array
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false; // only return false if all failed
}
```

Comment: Ah thanks, that might explain why values aren't returning as expected!

Comment: Sorry I can't accept 2 answers else I would accept this as well!